# Problem with permissions - Deny: Add and adjust pages - although custom scripts are allowed

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, modern-pages, modern-team-site

I want to move pages from the site library to other libraries within and outside my site collection. I have already written down more information about my requirements in this question:

[What options do I have to change the structure and move modern pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276049/what-options-do-i-have-to-change-the-structure-and-move-modern-pages)

To be able to move pages (with the windows file explorer) I should set the following settings in the admin center (see screenshot).

[image: settings in admin center]

I have set these settings, but moving pages still does not work...
When I check my permissions, I realize that I am not allowed to add and adjust pages.

[image: permissions]

- What else can I do?
- How can I change this permission?
- How can I move pages (without third-party tools)?

Note: Due to company regulations I unfortunately **cannot use** the SharePoint Online Management Shell.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. Any change to the scripting setting made through the SharePoint Online admin center may take up to 24 hours to take effect. Usually changing these two settings will solve this issue.
2. Check the user permission in this site via the Site permission page and make sure the permission level “Edit Page” is included.
3. You can use Microsoft Flow to create a copy of Site Page in another site.

   Here’s another post for your reference:
   [Copy or Move Site Page from one site to another.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/copy-or-move-site-page-from-one-site-to-another/m-p/255703)

Comment: 1.) I have waited more than 24 hours without success. 2.) This permission is included

Comment: @SharePointNewbie Are you allowed to install SharePoint Online PowerShell module on Windows PowerShell?  The command "Set-SPOSite $SiteURL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False" should be able to give you the permission right away.

Comment: Internal regulations do not allow me to install a PowerShell extension... but... Is this setting not the same as the one I set in the Admin Center? If the setting in the admin center has no effect, it probably won't work with your method with the powershell.

Comment: @SharePointNewbie Not really. I just fixed Navigation settings “Access Denied” issue with the same PowerShell command in one of my sites yesterday. It forces the site to allow page customization or enable custom script immediately although I have the features on all the time in admin center. I cannot tell why but it does work for me.